# AWS Cloud formation and my customised-built AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS cloud formation, i use the cloud former tool. I can use that tool to create a cloud formation template from existing resources. And then use the template to create a stack. I tested with that tool. It can work, (as in it can create instances with same memory size, with same volume size, same VPC settings, and auto start the instances). But there is no files in the volume.

How can i choose my customised-built AMI in the cloud former tool? I do not see such option. Is there such option?

Answer (score 1):

In the Resources section of your template there will be a declaration of a `"Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",`

One of the Properties for that is an `ImageId`

set that property to your customised AMI id and Cloudformation will use it to make the EC2

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html